# 16 Nested for loops binary number bug

Tags: javascript

I was working on an experiment to count in binary with extreme ease, and it worked with 8 loops (simulating 8 bytes) but mysteriously broke when I upped it to 16.
Here's the code:

```
for(var a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
for(var b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
for(var c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
    for(var d = 0; d < 2; d++) {
    for(var e = 0; e < 2; e++) {
        for(var f = 0; f < 2; f++) {
        for(var g = 0; g < 2; g++) {
            for(var h = 0; h < 2; h++) {
            for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                for(var j = o; j < 2; j++) {
                for(var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                    for(var l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
                    for(var m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
                        for(var n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
                        for(var o = 0; o < 2; o++) {
                            for(var p = 0; p < 2; p++) {
                            document.writeln(a + "" + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p);
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aufex8c9/1/

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218377/is-there-a-limit-to-how-many-levels-you-can-nest-in-javascript

Comment: You are setting `j` to the letter o instead of zero (0).

Comment: It mysteriously works if you fix the typo. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the letter `o` instead of the number zero in the loop for `j`.

Change this line:

```
for(var j = o; j < 2; j++) {
```

to

```
for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
```