# ignite web console stack exceeded in big project

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Im using ignite web console in my project, which is erp based , we have more than 1000 table I tried to generate the caching using the egnite web console, the last is working just fine reading all my tables and generating all caches, however when I try to download the generated project or view it I m facing the following exceptions

> Failed to generate project preview: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

generating project

> Failed to generate project files. Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Is there there any known fix to this

the web-console stack is :

```
[2019-11-20T15:19:58,099][INFO ][applicationEventMulticasterThreadPool-1][Application] GridGain Web Console started on TCP port 3000 in 9.987 seconds
[2019-11-20T15:19:58,715][INFO ][qtp332564935-79][AgentsService] Agent session opened [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=47389db6, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/agents]]
[2019-11-20T15:19:58,729][INFO ][qtp332564935-74][AgentsService] Agent session opened [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=7f714a90, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/agents]]
[2019-11-20T15:19:58,804][INFO ][qtp332564935-73][AgentsService] Agent connected: AgentHandshakeRequest [ver=8.8.0, toks=[11aaa43a-8b81-49f3-88d5-fe08f2f733f3]]
[2019-11-20T15:19:58,804][INFO ][qtp332564935-77][AgentsService] Agent connected: AgentHandshakeRequest [ver=8.8.0, toks=[11aaa43a-8b81-49f3-88d5-fe08f2f733f3]]
[2019-11-20T15:19:58,807][INFO ][qtp332564935-73][AgentsService] Agent session closed [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=47389db6, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/agents], status=CloseStatus[code=1001, reason=Shutdown]]
[2019-11-20T15:19:59,509][INFO ][qtp332564935-75][BrowsersService] Browser session opened [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=68d51f39, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/browsers?demoMode=false]]
[2019-11-20T15:20:45,689][INFO ][qtp332564935-94][BrowsersService] Browser session closed [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=68d51f39, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/browsers?demoMode=false], status=CloseStatus[code=1001, reason=null]]
[2019-11-20T15:20:47,556][INFO ][qtp332564935-95][BrowsersService] Browser session opened [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=199ce2d1, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/browsers?demoMode=false]]
[2019-11-20T15:22:31,249][INFO ][qtp332564935-78][AgentsService] Agent session closed [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=7f714a90, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/agents], status=CloseStatus[code=1001, reason=Shutdown]]
[2019-11-20T15:22:43,783][INFO ][qtp332564935-95][AgentsService] Agent session opened [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=6b2805e4, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/agents]]
[2019-11-20T15:22:43,952][INFO ][qtp332564935-78][AgentsService] Agent connected: AgentHandshakeRequest [ver=8.8.0, toks=[11aaa43a-8b81-49f3-88d5-fe08f2f733f3]]
^C[2019-11-20T15:23:32,100][INFO ][Thread-16][AgentsService] Agent session closed [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=6b2805e4, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/agents], status=CloseStatus[code=1006, reason=Disconnected]]
[2019-11-20T15:23:32,114][INFO ][Thread-16][BrowsersService] Browser session closed [socket=JettyWebSocketSession[id=199ce2d1, uri=ws://192.168.1.60:3000/browsers?demoMode=false], status=CloseStatus[code=1006, reason=Disconnected]]
[2019-11-20T15:23:32,156][WARN ][qtp332564935-73][HttpChannel] /agents
org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@64a71d5f[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 514]] did not accept task: org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1@2f918563
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:304) ~[spring-context-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) ~[spring-context-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1073) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:231) ~[websocket-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:171) ~[spring-session-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) ~[spring-session-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.20.RELEASE.jar:1.5.20.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-security-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502) ~[jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370) [jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267) [jetty-server-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305) [jetty-io-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [jetty-io-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) [jetty-io-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) [jetty-util-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) [jetty-util-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) [jetty-util-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) [jetty-util-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) [jetty-util-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765) [jetty-util-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683) [jetty-util-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:9.4.15.v20190215]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_232]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1@2f918563 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@64a71d5f[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 514]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:301) ~[spring-context-4.3.23.RELEASE.jar:4.3.23.RELEASE]
    ... 102 more
```

Comment: Have you tried the new Java Web Console? Available for download from GridGain downloads section.

Comment: Hello, can you attach the full stacktrace, please?

Comment: @alamaryes I m in the last version, I just installed it this morning

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb the error comes from WC UI, ZIP with project is generated in browser from the model stored on backend. I suggest to check out your browser JS console, check out worker threads too. It would help to know what function exactly exhausts the stack. I'm not sure project generation was even tested with so much SQL tables.

Comment: @Klaster_1 there is also the possibility that is angular related or js related I feel like the rendrer is assumig my big data as infinit loop so blocking and raising the exception. knowing i m able to see all my 1054 generated caches

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb I'll try to check the "Project Preview" dialog with lots of mock data and see what exactly happens, but no promises. It's either the project sources generator, or sources zipping, or display issue. Hard to tell without a proper trace.

Comment: @Klaster_1 I have around 1100 table every table have arround max 30 to 15 field at least, I have some composite key fields, you can reproduce it on compiere erp database because I m using it, I believe that wordpress database could be also a good fit to test on it .

Comment: I've found the cause (too deep recursion when gathering configuration imports in project code generator) and am working on a fix. More updates and an answer will come later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say this was *a stack overflow issue*

It was caused by suboptimal project generation in Web Console frontend: the method responsible for import gathering relied heavily on recursion, which in turn exhausted the stack very fast on configurations of over ~800 caches/nodes. To fix it, [we replaced recursion with a visitor](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/pull/758/files#diff-db2bb79e656d4e0538367d9e6e73e23a). I've checked the fix on configurations of up to 10k caches/nodes, and while it might make some time to complete and render, no error is thrown anymore.

Hypothetically, [a workaround is possible if you tweak browser stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49601237/333777), but I did not try it and errors/crashes might still happen on big enough configurations.

The fix was released as a part of GridGain Web Console 2019.12.02, it should become available on [GridGain downloads page](https://www.gridgain.com/resources/download) in a couple of days. No previous version contains the fix, relevant code remained unchanged since initial Web Console version, so @dmagda's answer was wrong until today.

Comment: Thanks That's great news for me, I ll make a feedback as soon as possible I go back to the gridgain compiere project ( it is on hold unfortunately )

Answer (score -1):

Use GridGain WebConsole that can be downloaded from their website. It’s free, goes in a binary and docker package, and supports monitoring dashboard. Not sure that Ignite WebConsole is actively maintained.